# Yield thread back to Office via modal WinForm (VSTO)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, vsto, clipboard

I have a difficult behaviour to reproduce, yet consistently firing back through a few users (which happen to be often the same ones, but not always): on a VSTO add-in (Excel here), take an `Excel.Shape`, `.Duplicate` it, then `.Copy` it, then `DifferentSpreadsheet.Paste` it, and an `Exception` throws either at `.Copy` or at `.Paste`.

### Things I have tried

I share here my experience not only for the purpose of demonstrating the topic has been researched, but also in case someone faced a similar issue. I was stuck for months and would be very happy to save anyone going through the same.

The **first workaround** was to insert a `Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan>0)` between`.Copy` and `.Paste`. This resolved around **70%** of the `Exceptions`, I believe due to race conditions with the clipboard.

The **second workaround** was to ask all users to turn off the Office Clipboard. This tool was developed by Microsoft decades ago, with a fairly limited success; but they seem to recently be trying to push users to use it by silently activating it for all Office 365 users. The trap is that even when the Office Clipboard panel is closed, it keeps collecting and seems to lock access to newly created object until Office (here Excel) has had the UI thread back. This resolved **25%** of the `Exceptions`.

But we still had **5%** of cases where we would have no idea what was going on. These 5% could be a few users from a company where dozens of other users did not have any problems and all machines were supposedly configured in a similar way. But it could also be a random user once in a while who never had the issue before and would never get it again after trying once again.
After suspecting what was happening with the Office Clipboard was that Office needed to get its UI thread back so that it could free the object, I started to make my code asynchronous, with the aim to `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan)` before `.Copy` and before `.Paste`. The annoying part was that this involved re-typing loads of code, making the entire stack from the Click Event to the Copy/Pasting a chain of `Async Function`s returning `Task`s or `Tasks(Of T)`, etc; while all I needed was to yield back the thread at one or two specific places. In other words, this impacted huge chunks of objects, propagating all the way up the stack, and would inevitably affect maintenance.

### The current solution

So I implemented a WinForm called via `.ShowDialog`. This WinForm has a `Windows.Forms.Timer` which `Ticks` after the required duration. When it ticks, the WinForm is `.Close`d.
It works like magic, we now have 0% bugs even when the Office Clipboard is activated. Yet, to me this looks like a hack/smell, and I would like to implement something cleaner.

Are there any alternatives other than awaiting a `Task.Delay`?

In order to maybe find an alternative myself, could anyone help me understand what happens in the background of `.ShowDialog`? I highly suspect there is some Async there, yet I am puzzeld in understanding how .Net knows where to continue while awaiting the modal form to respond.

### Source code & Usage Sample

```vb
''' <summary>
    ''' Allows to yield the UI thread back to the office application.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Class YieldThread

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Yields the UI thread back to the office application, for a given duration.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="Duration">The duration during which the UI thread is yielded.</param>
        Shared Sub During(Duration As TimeSpan)
            Dim NewForm As New YieldThreadForm(Duration)
            NewForm.ShowDialog()
        End Sub

    End Class

    Friend Class YieldThreadForm

        Private WithEvents Timer As Windows.Forms.Timer

        Public Sub New(Delay As TimeSpan)
            InitializeComponent()
            Me.Timer = New Windows.Forms.Timer
            Me.Timer.Interval = CInt(Delay.TotalMilliseconds)
        End Sub

        Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
            Me.Close()
        End Sub

        Private Sub YieldThreadForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
            Me.Timer.Start()
        End Sub

    End Class


Class Main 'USAGE

    Sub Main(Shape as Excel.Shape, Sheet as Excel.Worksheet)
        Dim NewShape as Excel.Shape = Shape.Duplicate
        YieldThread.During(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
        Shape.Copy
        Sheet.Paste
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This might be a good use case for `DoEvents` or equivalent.  I have a COM automation code that I wrote where I spin up a thread to wait for an event (equivalent in your case would be to wait out the timeout) and release the dispatcher frame once that happens, then spin the message loop on the main thread until it's time to continue.

Comment: But for this to work, there would need to be a `Dispatcher` in the context of the code, and I'm not completely certain that's the case where it's an add-in.

Comment: Haha at first I had actually named the `YieldThread` class `OfficeDoEvents`. Under VBA I would do a DoEvents, but unless I am mistaken there is no such thing for VSTO? We also have a custom Scheduler associated to a Timer in order to schedule lambdas for the next 200-ish ms (useful to capture multiple clicks on a Ribbon). But for the purpose of Copy/Pasting, that means splitting half of the logic into a lambda/task and that is a lot of burden for maintainability.. (execute First-50%, schedule Remaining-50%-Lambda, execute lambda)

Comment: It depends on there being a `Dispatcher`.  If there is, then there's an equivalent for `DoEvents` (which in .NET land is basically just pushing a dispatcher frame that clears out the message queue and returns).  It might need to be hand-coded, but it's not magic once you know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain it will be helpful for you, but I'll show you how I did a pumping wait for something to happen in my own automation code.  This requires that there be an active `Dispatcher` because it relies on `Dispatcher.PushFrame` to pump messages until it's ready to continue.

```
Function WaitForEvent(ByVal eventHandle as EventWaitHandle, Optional ByVal timeout As Integer = Timeout.Infinite) As Boolean
    Dim isEventSignaled As Boolean = False

    Dim frame = New DispatcherFrame()

    Dim t = New Thread(Sub()
                           isEventSignaled = eventHandle.WaitOne(timeout)
                           frame.Continue = False
                       End Sub)
    t.Start()
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame)

    Return isEventSignaled
End Function
```

You might just do a fixed wait (e.g. doing `Task.Delay` on an `Async Sub`) instead of looking for an event to be signaled; in my case, I had a .NET event handler (for a COM event) that would flip the Windows event to signaled.

(Apologies for any confusion about which "event" is which in the last paragraph, there are three different kinds of "event" all being discussed here!)

Comment: I will investigate what a dispatcher is, not yet familiar with it. One important thing to note is that VSTO does not allow multithreading: all calls on the Office Interop API must be done through the UI thread. This is usually achieved by setting `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(ThreadingWindowsContext)`. Would that be problematic for the use of a Dispatcher?

Comment: @Ama Is it the case that it doesn't allow multithreading at all, or just that everything that talks to Office must be on the UI thread?  If the latter, then it wouldn't necessarily be an issue to start a thread just to wait.  If the former, then you might still be able to run a `DoEvents` style loop but you would need to do it a little differently than how I implemented it here.

Comment: The VSTO app can perform multithreading, just the talk with Office must be done exclusively through the UI thread. So for example our Scheduler uses `Windows.Forms.Timer` rather than `System.Timers.Timer`, because it runs from the IU thread. But for example we can make async/multithread calls to a network no problem.